# Cite citation with BibTeX

Tags: bibtex, citing

I want to cite a refrence in a primary source that is already a citation from a secondary source. As far as I know, I have to refer to both the citing author and the original author of the quote.

The quote is as follows:

> "[...] a change made to the internal structure of software to make it easier to understand and cheaper to modify without changing its observable behavior."

I read it in Kerievsky, *Refactoring to Patterns*, 2005. It was originally written by Fowler in *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code*, 1999.

Citing in text, I would write something like this:

> Refactoring is "..." [Fowler 1999 cited by Kerievsky 2005].

Here is a minimal working example, which just places both references in brackets:

```
\documentclass{memoir}    
\usepackage{natbib}    
\begin{document}

According to Martin Fowler, refactoring is ``a change made to the internal
structure of software to make it easier to understand and cheaper to modify
without changing its observable behavior''~\cite{Fow:1999,Ker:2005}.

\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

Using BibTeX, this is not so straight forward anymore. I use numbers for citations and print the bibliography in the appendix. What would be a best practice solution for citing citations with BibTeX?

Comment: are you using `natbib`? Because then you might be able to get by using `\citealt` and `\citetext`. BTW: next time please include a minimal example, such we we now such things from the start. Makes it a lot easier to help.

Comment: No, I'm not using `natbib`. If it helps, I can edit my question and add a minimal working example.

Comment: Do that, otherwise it is nearly impossible to help

Comment: I just added a minimal working example, already using `natbib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the sake of argument, I'll assume that there are entries with keys `Ker:2005` and `Fow:1999` in your `.bib` file which point to the pieces by Kerievsky and Fowler, respectively. 
Assuming you use the `natbib` citation management package, you could proceed as follows.

- Load the `natbib` package with the options `square` (to produce square brackets around the parenthetical citations) and `numbers` (to produce numeric-style citations).
- Use a combination of `\citep` and `\citealp` to create the desired citation:

  ```
  Refactoring is "..." \citep[][cited by \citealp{Ker:2005}]{Fow:1999}.
  ```

If this syntax looks like it's going to be a bit hard to remember, you might want to define a macro named `\citeprimsec` in the preamble:

```
\newcommand{\citeprimsec}[2]{\citep[][cited by \citealp{#2}]{#1}}
```

and employ it in the body of the document as

```
Refactoring is "..." \citeprimsec{Fow:1999}{Ker:2005}.
```

The name of the macro will hopefully make it more or less obvious that the first argument should be the key of the primary reference and that its second argument should be the key of the secondary reference.

---

*Addendum*: I just noticed that your comment that you do *not* use `natbib`. Well, adding `natbib` to the list of packages you load in the preamble shouldn't be a big deal. Just be sure to load it with the options `square` and `numbers`. You needn't modify any of your existing `\cite` commands.

Comment: The OP just mentioned that `natbib` is not used.

Comment: But I can consider using `natbib`. I'll give this answer a try and will report back.

Comment: @daleif - I too just noticed that OP has mentioned non-use of `natbib` in a comment. As I note in the just-posted addendum, starting to load `natbib` shouldn't be much of a hardship. :-)

Comment: It of course depends on whether the style in use is compatible. Will have to see until the OP posts a MWE.

Comment: The style matches. This answer is perfect, thanks a lot! I would just change *cited by* to *cited in*.