# Customized citation for secondary quotes ("quoted in")

Tags: biblatex, citing

i'd like to customize the citation style for secondary citations. At the moment it looks like this:
[image]
but i want to look the citation like this:
[image]

Is there any chance to create a citation style which is doing this?
Here is an minimal example of the code i'm using including the customization for using 4 letters and the "-" for the cite.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, oneside, parskip=half+, numbers=noenddot]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{filecontents} 

\begin{filecontents}{Minimalbeispiel.bib} 
@book{Bechte.1984,
    author = {Bechte, Wolfgang},
    year = {1984},
    title = {{Steuerung der Durchlaufzeit durch belastungsorientierte      Auftragsfreigabe bei Werkst{\"a}ttenfertigung. Diss. Univ. Hannover}},
    address = {D{\"u}sseldorf},
    volume = {2},
    number ={70},
    publisher = {VDI-Verlag},
    series = {{Fortschritt-Berichte}}
}

@book{Wiendahl.2005,
    author = {Wiendahl, Hans-Peter},
    year = {2005},
    title = {{Betriebsorganisation f{\"u}r Ingenieure}},
    address = {M{\"u}nchen},
    edition = {5. aktualisierte Aufl.},
    publisher = {Hanser},
    isbn = {3446228535}
    }
\end{filecontents}  
\usepackage[babel, german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[
backend=biber, 
style=alphabetic, 
pagetracker=true, 
maxbibnames=99,
backref=false, 
natbib=true, 
firstinits=true, 
sorting=nyt, 
isbn=false,
url=false,
doi=false]{biblatex} 

\AtBeginBibliography{% 
    \renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
    \renewcommand*{\labelnamepunct}{\addcolon\addspace}
}
\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}

\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
    \labelelement{
        \field[final]{shorthand}
        \field{label}
        \field[strwidth=4,strside=left,ifnames=1]{labelname}
        \field[strwidth=2,strside=left,ifnames=2]{labelname}
        \field[strwidth=1,strside=left]{labelname}
    }
    \labelelement{ 
        \literal{-} 
    } 
    \labelelement{
        \field[strwidth=2,strside=right]{year}
    }
}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}



\addbibresource{Minimalbeispiel.bib} 

\begin{document}
Interesting stuff. \cite{Bechte.1984} quoted in \cite[S. 266f.]{Wiendahl.2005}

\par

Interesting stuff. [Bech-84 quoted in Wien-05, S. 266f.]

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe [Cite citation with BibTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/139425/35864) can help if you don't need something fancy.

Comment: @moewe That means switching from Biblatex, though.

Comment: Does my question at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213185/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-cite-two-things-connected-by-a-joining-word-wi help at all?

Comment: @cfr Well, you could adapt the solution for `biblatex` as well. (Of course one might get into trouble with the square brackets here ...)

Comment: @cfr Thanks. It works fine with your code. I just changed the brackets.

Comment: Great! In that case, this should probably be closed as a duplicate so people can use it as a sign-post to a solution.